# How high do I have to count before I hit an MD5 hash collision?

Tags: md5

Never mind why I'm doing this -- this is mainly theoretical.

If I were MD5 hashing string representations of integers, how high would I have to count before two of the hashes collide?

Comment: It would be a certainty that you would have a collision if you counted from 0 to 1 + 2^128.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem (in generic case) is known as  [Birthday Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

The probability of collision in generic case can be computed easily. However, in your particular case, you have to actually compute (and store!) each MD5.

EDIT @Scott : not really. The Pigeonhole principle (being just a particular case of Birthday problem) would say that having 2^128 possible MD5 values, we surely will have a collision after 1 + 2^128 tries. The birthday paradox says that  the probability of collision will be grater than 0.5 for about 2^70 MD5 values.

With these estimates for storage requirements, it's up to you to decide if the problem worth it. By me it does not.

Comment: No it is not. This is a example of the [Pigeonhole Pricipal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, one can [base a thesis on this very thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HashClash) (or similar problems, anyway).  I haven't read it, but maybe something in Stevens' thesis will help you (it's apparently linked from the Wikipedia article).

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world, to `1 + 2^128`. But I doubt md5 is perfect, I cant give you a number but is guaranteed to be `<= 1+ 2^128`

Comment: I suppose what I'm really asking is whether anyone has actually tried computing and storing the hashes of "0", "1", "2" and so on until a collision has occurred, or has given up at some known (high) number after no collisions.

Comment: I am sure people have done this for fun the problem is the data required to store all the results to test it is unfeasible 5,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 Gigabytes would be required (SO striped out the astrix from my link just copy and paste it. http://www.google.com/search?q=128+bits+*+2^128+in+gigabytes)

Comment: @Scott: Only if you generate and store all the MD5 hashes before you start comparing. If you start with the first hash and start scanning for a collision, then the second hash, then your constraint simply becomes processor time. Alternatively, it may be possible to more efficiently store the source data in a binary tree that represents the bits in the resulting hash.

Comment: @Brianary: good point, but it still will require a ton a space. lets say you find the collision in the first .1% of the keyspace, and lets say the binary tree takes .1% of the original size to store that is still about 507,060,240,000,000,000,000,000 gigabytes to test

Comment: @Scott: Agreed. You'd really have to focus on a fraction of the tree at a time, discarding the rest of it as it is generated. But that's OK, because you'd probably want to partition the task for multiple machines anyway.

Comment: @Scott: If you were in fact going to test the whole range of MD5 hashes, instead of storing each MD5 hash (128 bits times 2^128), you could just store 2^128 sequential bits (partitioned off across multiple machines) and mark each one when it is taken and then detect when it gets double marked. Of course, that would still require 39,614,081,300,000,000,000,000,000,000 Gigabyes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scientific way to find out an estimate of how high you would have to count.

Make MD5 hash that is cut down to say 4 bits. Calculate that (make sure you calculate until you reach say 100 collisions so you get a good average)

Then make the same thing at 8 bits (again, wait for many collisions so you can calculate an average).

Do it again and again until you have averages for 4, 8, 12, 16 bits and then see if you can find a trend. Follow that trend up to 128 bits

You may want to xor all 128 bits to come up with your shorter version. Taking the first or last part may not be the best test.